# AngularJs : does ui-router *require* me to inject $scope into my controller (even with Controller As syntax)?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

One of the advantages of the "Controller As" syntax is that it frees us from $scope.

BUT, I am having problems which seem to indicate that `ui-router` requires `$scope` - probably to access the state.

There are multiple similar questions, not with a satisfactory answer, so I am looking for a canonical answer, which I can refer those other questions to.

1. does `ui-router` ***require*** me to inject `$scope` into my controller, even if the controller code never references `$scope` (because I am using "controller as" syntax)?  (the answer to [Angular ui router controlleras syntax not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824679/angular-ui-router-controlleras-syntax-not-working) seems to imply that it does. Also, removing the injection of `$scope` into [this working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CYeZOCofstVpSLONLLt2?p=preview) breaks it)
2. can I avoid that (possibly by telling my `ui-router` config to get the state from the controller of the "controller as" declaration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following code could be useful.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('helloworld', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider) {
  var helloState = {
    name: 'hello',
    url: '/hello',
    template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>'
  }
  
  class AboutStateController {
    constructor() {
      this.name = 'John Dow';
    }
  }
 
  var aboutState = {
    name: 'about',
    url: '/about',
    template: '<h3>Hello <span>{{aboutStateController.name}}</span></h3>',
    controller: AboutStateController,
    controllerAs: 'aboutStateController'
  }

  $stateProvider.state(helloState);
  $stateProvider.state(aboutState);
});

angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['helloworld']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <a ui-sref="hello" ui-sref-active="active">Hello</a>
    <a ui-sref="about" ui-sref-active="active">About</a>

    <ui-view></ui-view>
```

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you. You have proven that it is not necessary to inject $scope into a  controller for ui-router to work. I would like to award you an extra 100 points for such a good answer - but the system will not let me do so for 2 more days (to give others time to answer). If I forget, please comment here to prompt me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No, UI-Router **does not require $scope** in its controllers:

```
myapp.controller('MicrositeController', ['$state', '$mdMedia', '$mdSidenav',
 function($state, $mdMedia, $mdSidenav) {
  console.log("MicrositeController instantiated");
  var vm = this;
  vm.page_name = $state.current.data.page_name;
  vm.sidenav_locked_open = false;

  vm.toggleSideNav = function() {
    if ($mdMedia('gt-sm')) {
      vm.sidenav_locked_open = !vm.sidenav_locked_open;
    } else {
      $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
    }
  }
}]);
```

```
$stateProvider
  .state('microsite', {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "microsite.tmpl.html",
      //Put controller on root state
      controller: 'MicrositeController as vm',
      abstract: true
})
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/t9L28K07cPpDyOWVh6KG?p=preview)